# How to find certain words in a text file, then find numbers in Java?

Tags: java, file, search, text

I have the following text file (answers.txt):

> Problem A: 23|47|32|20
>
> Problem B: 40|50|30|45
>
> Problem C: 5|8|11|14
>
> Problem D: 20|23|25|30

What I need is something that will read the problem that I tell it(Problem A, Problem B), then read the numbers after it, which are separated by the lines, and print it out like this:

> Answers for Problem A: a.23 b.47 c.32 d.20

Does anyone know how this can be done? I've been stuck on it for a while.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Read the lines one by one, split the lines at " " first. The you will get an array with three parts "Problem", "A:" and "23|47|32|20". Then split the third part at "|" so you will get a second array with four parts "23,"47","32","20".

Combine all to get the output you want.

If you want info on how to read lines from a file, or spilt strings then there are billions of tutorials online on how to do that so I wont go into detail on how its done. IM sure you can find them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code!
It assumes that you have such file format:

```
Problem A:
23|7|32|20
Problem B:
40|50|30|45
Problem C:
5|8|11|14
Problem D:
20|23|25|30
```

because you wrote "numbers after it, which are separated by the lines"

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("answers.txt"));
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        dataList.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println(dataList);       
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i=0;i<dataList.size();i=i+2){
        map.put(dataList.get(i),dataList.get(i+1));
    }

    for(Entry<String,String> en:map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(en.getKey()+" : "+en.getValue());
    }
    String problemC = map.get("Problem C:");
    String splitted[] = problemC.split("\\|");
    System.out.println("Get me problem C: "+String.format("a:%s, b:%s, c:%s, d:%s",splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2],splitted[3]));
}
```

}

Comment: won't this split "Problem C:" into "Problem" and "C:"?

Comment: there "map.get("Problem C:");" not "Problem C:"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("answers.txt")));
    String lineRead  = null;
    String problem = "Problem A";//Get this from user Input
    List<String> numberData = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((lineRead = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        if(lineRead.contains(problem))
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(lineRead,":");
            String problemPart = st.nextToken();
            String numbersPart = st.nextToken();
            st = new StringTokenizer(lineRead,"|");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String number = st.nextToken();
                System.out.println("Number is: " + number);
                numberData.add(number);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Answers for " + problem + " : " + numberData );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines one by one, split the lines with `:`. The you will get an array with two parts "Problem A:" and "23|47|32|20". Then split the second part at "|" so you will get a second array with four parts "23,"47","32","20".

Combining all this you will get the output you want.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Scanner` and you can filter the integers in the file.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File ("answers.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is integer
        System.out.print(s.nextInt());
    } else {
        s.next(); // else read the next token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to read line by line ? If not , chect it [How to read a large text file line by line in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-in-java)

To sub your string data there have many ways to do. You can sub as you wish. Here for my code..

```
    String data = yourReader.readLine();
    String problem = data.substring("Problem".length(), data.indexOf(":"));
    System.err.println("Problem is " + problem);
    data = data.substring(data.indexOf(":") + 2, data.length());
    String[] temp = data.split("\\|");
    for (String result : temp) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always four possible answers as in your Example:

```
// read complete file in fileAsString
String regex = "^(Problem \\w+): (\\d+)\\|(\\d+)\\|(\\d+)\\|(\\d+)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileAsString);
//and so on, read all the Problems using matcher.find() and matcher.group(int) to get the parts
// put in a Map  maybe?
// output the one you want...
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest creating a simple data type for the purpose of organization:

```
public class ProblemAnswer {
  private final String problem;
  private final String[] answers;

  public ProblemAnswer(String problem, String[] answers) {
    this.problem = problem;
    this.answers = new String[answers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      this.answers[i] = answers[i];
    }
  }

  public String getProblem() {
    return this.problem;
  }

  public String[] getAnswers() {
    return this.answers;
  }

  public String getA() {
    return this.answers[0];
  }

  public String getB() {
    return this.answers[1];
  }

  public String getC() {
    return this.answers[2];
  }

  public String getD() {
    return this.answers[3];
  }
}
```

Then the reading from the text file would look something like this:

```
public void read() {
  Scanner s = new Scanner("answers.txt");
  ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (s.hasNext()) {
    lines.add(s.nextLine());//first separate by line  
  }
  ProblemAnswer[] answerKey = new ProblemAnswer[lines.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String[] divide = lines.get(i).split(": "); //0 is the problem name, 1 is the list                 
                                                //of answers
    String[] answers = divide[1].split("|");  //an array of the answers to a given
                                              //question
    answerKey[i] = new ProblemAnswer(divide[0], answers); //add a new ProblemAnswer 
                                                          //object to the key
  }
}
```

Now that leaves you with an answer key with ProblemAnswer objects which is easily checked
with a simple `.equals()` comparison on the `getProblem()` method, and whatever index is matched, you have all the answers neatly arranged right within that same object.